# Still Another Simple Separable Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please check my work.

> Problem: Solve for $y$:
>
> $$y'\sin 2x = \cos 2x$$

My solution:

$$\int \, dy = \int \cot 2x \, dx$$

$$\implies y = \dfrac{1}{2}\ln|\sin 2x| + c$$

My text has answer as:
$$y = c\sqrt{\sin 2x}$$

Please show why my solution is incorrect and guide me to the correct answer.

Comment: Maybe the book was solving $y'\sin 2x=y\cos 2x$.

Comment: Double check the initial equation. Very likely they solve $y'\sin{2x}=y\cos{2x}$.

Comment: you need to know your logarithm rules. 
$\frac{1}{2}ln \mid sin2x \mid + C$... that $\frac{1}{2}$ is the exponent number, so you will have something like $ y = ln \mid sin 2x \mid ^{\frac{1}{2}} + C$ which is $ y  = \sqrt{sin2x}C . $ The logarithmic rule for addition is also being used which is why the answer has $c$ together with $\sqrt{sin2x}$

Comment: errrrrrr you should take the ln on both sides and then use e^ on both sides. Since e and ln are inverses of each other, they cancel out.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is ok. But the answer you have provided from your text is not correct. That should be $e^y=C\sqrt{|\sin 2x|}$. For this, just take the constant as $\ln C$.

$$y=\ln |\sin 2x|^{1/2}+\ln C\Rightarrow y=\ln C\sqrt{|\sin 2x|}\Rightarrow e^y=C\sqrt{|\sin 2x|}$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick input.

Comment: $\ln$ and $\sqrt{\ }$ aren't the same function !

Comment: @Debashish could you elaborate your answer? I would like to see some justification before voting :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for pointing out. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @Debashish thanks! I am agree with you.

Comment: Also the book answer was in terms of y not $\mathrm{e}^y$. I was going to down vote, but since you actually solved the ode the OP provided I cannot do that.

Comment: @Jules Manson .. Please recheck the question or answer in your text and edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

That answer is definitely for $y'\sin2x=y\cos2x$, as:

$$\dfrac{y'}{y} = \dfrac{\cos2x}{\sin2x}$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{y} = \dfrac{\cos2x}{\sin2x}dx$$

$$\int\dfrac{1}{y}dy = \int\dfrac{\cos2x}{\sin2x}dx$$

$$\ln(y) = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\sin2x\right|+\ln(c)$$ 
(since who's to say this constant isn't the natural log of some other constant?)

$$\ln(y) = \ln c\sqrt{\sin2x}$$ (Following your log laws for powers and addition)

$$y = c\sqrt{\sin2x}$$

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y'}y=\frac{\cos2x}{\sin2x}=\frac12\frac{(\sin2x)'}{\sin2x}$$
$$ln|y|=\frac12ln|\sin2x|+c$$
$$y=\pm c\sqrt{|\sin2x|}=c\sqrt{|\sin2x|}$$

(The final transform emphasizes the fact that even if the multiplicative constant should be positive as being the exponential of another constant, a negative value is possible too due to the absolute value around $y$.)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.